# Installing English language package on Windows Vista German Edition

Tags: windows-vista

I have a German edition of Windows Vista Home. I would like to add English Language Speech Recognition support. Is this possible?

Comment: @Aarron - leave the tag - its removed at migration.

Answer (score 4):

**[Vistalizator](http://www.froggie.sk/)** allows you to change display language in Windows editions other than (officially supported) Ultimate, like Starter, Home Basic, Home Premium and Business/Professional.

Vistalizator overrides the limit of one MUI language on non-Ultimate Windows editions.
See details about using multiple languages in Windows.

Features:

> Works in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows
>   Vista/Windows 7
>
> Change Windows display language in
>   less than 5 minutes! (Express
>   installation mode)
>
> Uses official Microsoft Windows
>   language packs
>
> You can install all 36 MUI languages
>   and switch between them easily
>
> You can install 55 Vista LIP languages
>   on top of specific MUI languages
>
> Compatible with Vista Service Pack 1
>   and Vista Service Pack 2
>
> User Account Control (UAC) compliant -
>   prompts for administrative privileges
>
> Windows Speech Recognition works with
>   all supported languages:
>
> Chinese, English, French, **German**,
>   Japanese and Spanish
>
> Languages can be installed either in
>   Internal or in Express mode, see
>   details

[image]

Comment: Are there any legal issues in using Vistalizer?

Comment: Thanks, I am also interested in knowing whether there a legal issues in supplying Vistalizator with my commercial application that uses SAPI?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not positive on this, but the answer is quite likely no. You will have to get an Ultimate version to install the English Language Pack.